# In German, what would "raffen" be associated with?

Tags: meaning

What would the word *raffen* mean in general conversation? Not the Google definition. I am trying to pick a business name, and this came up as “to gather”, however some colleagues seem to think it means a miser, or a money grabber. I don’t want a company name that in common use means greedy. I am trying to find out what a German speaking person would feel or think when they heard the word *raffen*.

Comment: You should give more information about the kind of business you plan to name like that. Usually one would avoid naming a business "raffen" as in most contexts the word has negative connotation. But in very specific contexts this could be different, e.g. when you are working in creative industries and want to give your firm an ironic name.

Comment: Off topic or resolved comments removed. **Please do not abuse comments for discussions irrelevant to the question.**

Answer (score 9):

*Raffen* in the meaning you seem to be concerned about has definitely a negative connotation - "Geld raffen"  or "Reichtum raffen" would translate to grub or hog money or wealth and would probably not be appropriate for a company name.

The verb has some more meanings you apparently are not looking for like gathering clothing or, colloquially, understanding something.

Comment: Immer diese Rede von der Nebenbedeutung (connotation). Nein, das ist schon die Hauptbedeutung! Die kann sich nur an verschiedenem festmachen, an Segeln oder an Geld.

Comment: @userunknown Extra für dich: *connotation* darf man hier als "Unterton" verstehen. Man kann "Röcke raffen", damit man sie beim über die Strasse gehen nicht schmutzig macht und man kann dasselbe tun, indem man reihenweise Schränke damit füllt. Das sind definitiv zwei verschiedene Bedeutungen.

Comment: Aber beim Stoffraffen schwingt nichts von der angeblichen Konnotation mit. Deswegen ist es keine.

Comment: @userunknown Deswegen steht da ja auch nichts davon. Lies nochmal.

Answer (score 6):

In colloquial speech *raffen* is (very much like *to gather*) often used in the meaning of *to understand* or *to comprehend*.

> Ich raff das nicht, kannst Du mir das näher erklären?
>   Hast Du es jetzt gerafft?

A name for an informative or educational business like e.g.

> Ich raff das!

would be prefectly fine. No negative connotation to this. But keep in mind that *raffen* then would be colloquial speech used amongst (nowadays not more so) younger people and should not be used in a formal setting.

Today amongst young people *[checken](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/checken)* is used rather than *raffen* (confirmed by my teenaged children):

> Ich check das nicht... Checkst Du's jetzt?

Jemand, der es *blickt* oder *rafft*, wäre also heute ein *[Checker](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Checker)* (oder, falls nicht, ein *Non-Checker*).

Comment: Wobei "Checker" auch einen Halbstarken bezeichnet. Nicht jeder, der was checkt ist ein Checker und nicht jeder Checker checkt überhaupt noch was.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it is helpful to see the broader semantic field

*raffen* - (directly) Stoff in Falten zusammenlegen (see also *reffen* - the same thing for sails on a sailing boat)

*raffen* - (metaphorically) Dinge an sich reißen, zusammenhäufen...

*Raffgier* - der Drang, Geld o.ä. an sich zu reißen, ohne Rücksicht auf andere

*Raffzahn* - ein Mensch, der solchen Drang verspührt bzw. so handelt

If you think your company is described well by this word, then go for it. (Is it a bank?)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your company. There is no general conversation without context.

- in connection with textiles or sailing, it's fine
- with money, credits, insurance, I would stay away from it
- with intelligence, learning, quizzes etc. again fine

You need to take care about ads, that people don't miss the context, and get the wrong impression first.